# Error when trying to include stripe.php

Tags: php, include, include-path, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe for payment processing. I got everything running smoothly from my local machine, and everything ran smoothly on a secondary server as well.

However, when I copied everything over to the live server, the site throws an error when trying to include Stripe.php:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => include(): Failed opening 'stripe/lib/stripe.php' for inclusion    
    (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php6')
    [file] => /..../stripeprocess.php
    [line] => 10
)
```

Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: What kind of path is `/..../stripeprocess.php`? That doesn't look valid at all. Also, what is `php6`? we're only up to `5.4`.

Comment: You know PHP6. Full unicode [and shit](http://www.amazon.com/PHP-MySQL-Dynamic-Web-Sites/dp/032152599X)! :-)

Comment: Sorry, ... was just in lieu of remaining path. And I have no clue why it's php6 - the htaccess file may have done that but I edited it now. I'm not sure why it still says php6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct the path to the include, or use the full path, or set your local include path via set_include_path().  /..../ doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Although you didn't really add more info than I knew, your comment made me recheck the filename - turns out one was capitalized while the other wasn't. Thanks.

Comment: Was going to ask if the filesystem was case sensitive and if you had checked but figured you would have checked that first :) Have fun!

Comment: Lol I would have checked first, but it worked on both my local machine AND a separate server. Just goes to show that HKI is usually the issue :D